# Force users to go through a proxy server?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, proxy

I need to force my users on my network to use a transparent proxy server outside my network to access websites. I'm not sure if I can do this with DNS, by setting up my own DNS which redirects them to the proxy server. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to lock the users to a browser that honors the global proxy setting on a system (such as IE on Windows with GPO that applies proxy), but that also requires that you have total control of *all* clients on your network.

The other option is to redirect every packet destined for HTTP(80)/HTTPS(443) to a Proxy server with transparent support. There are a *ton* of options here, and we have no idea what kind of router or firewall you have for the redirect part.

One popular solution is WCCP/WCCP2 against Squid.